# Normalizing constraint coefficient norm in pyomo

Tags: optimization, pyomo

I have a pyomo concrete model.

```
import pyomo.environ as po
m = po.ConcreteModel()
m.x = po.Var()
m.y = po.Var()
```

Some of linear constraints are very large c.f. some others e.g.

```
m.c = po.ConstraintList()
m.c.add(m.x + m.y <= 2)  # small coefficients
m.c.add(1000*m.x + 2000*m.y <= 3000)  # large coefficients
```

Norm of coefficients are in o(1), o(1000). It seems this difference may cause slowing down or accuracy reduction in some solvers.

Is there anyway to normalize the coefficients? I try parsing the constraint body expression but it is very time consuming. Even a simplified coefficients (e.g. `x+2x=>3x`) of constraint is useful.

I try parsing the constraint body expression but it is very time consuming